# External hard drive not showing up in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, device-manager, disk-management

I recently Installed windows 10 on my laptop. just after windows was done applying some updates It doesn't show my External Hard drive and USB flash memory! these hardwares show up everywhere like Device Manager, control panel, safety remove (task bar)... But they don't show up in the explorer! 
(sometimes show up just a second and disappear)
Disk management or other partitioning softwares can't assign a letter to them!
I've already tried many solutions I could find on the web, none of them works for me!!!